# Virus - Hearing "Congratulations, you won!"

Tags: windows, virus

I'm having a virus currently with my computer that needs fixing.

I'm hearing a voice saying "Congratulations, you won!" at seemingly random intervals from my computer.

I'm saying at random because sometimes it can be 5 times an hour, then the next time it can be days before I hear it again.

Scanned my whole computer for viruses with AVG and Spybot, with no results.

Google sent me back results 4 years old, and that did things with the computer I wouldn't trust random strangers to inform me about.

Comment: *> Google sent me back results 4 years old* “Years”‽ On the very [first page](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22congratulations+you+won%22+virus), there are [three](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/298295-google-redirect-and-congratulations-you-won-virus/) [search](http://forums.techguy.org/virus-other-malware-removal/1028520-congratulations-you-won-audio-virus-2.html) [results](http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic173989.html) that are only three months old (some new virus), in which the issue was resolved.

Comment: Seems that I failed at choosing some keywords.

Comment: This isn’t a virus. You won.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It could be a webpage you are on having an ad , possibly a popunder  - if you're using firefox or chrome get adblock plus. If you're running windows 7, keep the audio mixer open to see what process is creating the sound.

Comment: I'm already equipped with Adblock plus, and the sound already happened while no browsers had open windows. So I have to discard this option.

Comment: Well, after close inspection, it seems that it's coming on most of the time when I'm watching Youtube Videos... and the audio mixer sees the sound as coming from Flash Player.

Comment: which backs up part of my original hypothesis, that its a rogue ad. If its persistant between boots, i'd take a look at my startup list with autoruns to try to see what suspecious things are there

Comment: I'll confirm this tonight, but yesterday, I uninstalled Chrome (My main browser where I heard the sound) and reinstalled it. I continued watching YT videos without hearing the sound at all. Let's see if it did fix it.

Comment: Seems it fixed it. Thanks guys.
So I just had to reinstall chorme (and thus, my flash player) and its gone. For the moment. If it just went sleeping to pop back up, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: Anyone know where this is being served from so we can just block DNS entries?

Answer (score 2):

This is coming from an ad served inside of Flash. At least, I get exactly the same thing and I know with certainty that it comes from my use of tinychat (to watch a friend's puppy during the day).

In my case, the ad is served as part of the tinychat flash app. I don't use adblock but I do use flashblock. Doesn't help here because I need to allow the specific tinychat flash app in order for tinychat to work, and it's that app that serves the ad, too.

I haven't seen the ad served outside of tinychat, but it's annoying enough that I close down my browser once tinychat serves it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I believe I dealt with the problem as I have had the same annoying voice randomly popping out of nowhere. You need to get an add-on for your browser that gets rid of "super-cookies" or LSO's which the browser by default cannot get rid of on it's own. I had the problem on firefox and since I installed better privacy (google it) I haven't heard the voice again. If it's on Chrome or another browser just find the equivilent. Hope that helped to kill that annoying guy's voice forever!